# Deleting Outliers and Compute for the Average Using Mysql

Tags: mysql, sql, window-functions, outliers

I am computing for the average lead time after outliers are removed. I have both z-scores and standard deviation to do the calculation.

I have used this sql query:

```
SELECT *
FROM (
    SELECT
        ROUND(AVG(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)),2) AS actual_ave_lead_time,
        DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) - AVG(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date))/
        STDDEV(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)) AS zscore
    FROM orders
) AS score_table
WHERE zscore BETWEEN zscore<1.96 AND >-.96;
```

I am expecting to get the overall average of the actual_ave_lead_time.

Comment: In `WHERE zscore BETWEEN zscore<1.96 AND >-.96;` there is a problem. Should be rewritten to `WHERE zscore zscore<1.96 AND zscore >-1.96;`

Comment: It is not working. I have added = after where zscore=. And this works.

Comment: @nnichols. This does not show any result.

Comment: Your inner query is [non-deterministic](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html#:~:text=values%20chosen%20are-,nondeterministic,-%2C%20which%20is%20probably) and only returning one row. It should be returning a 1140 error but you have [ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_only_full_group_by) disabled. [MySQL Handling of GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-handling.html)

Comment: If `zscore` is `FLOAT` or `DOUBLE`, you cannot trust whether `1.96` will actually equal `1.96`.  `DECIMAL` does not have that problem.  Please provide `SHOW CREATE TABLE`.

Comment: @RickJames Good spot. Due to the division by `STDDEV()`, zscore will always be `DOUBLE`.

Answer (score 2):

To calculate your z-scores you need to run the calculation (`z = (x-μ)/σ`) per order. The innermost sub-query calculates the `AVG()` and `STDDEV()` for the full set of orders, which is then joined to the orders to calculate the z-scores, which can then be used to exclude the outliers from the outermost `AVG()` -

```
SELECT AVG(lead_time)
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) AS lead_time,
        (DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) - avg_lead_time) / stddev_lead_time AS zscore
    FROM orders o
    JOIN (
        SELECT
            AVG(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)) AS avg_lead_time,
            STDDEV(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)) AS stddev_lead_time
        FROM orders
    ) s
    HAVING zscore BETWEEN -0.96 AND 1.96
) t;
```

If you are using MySQL 8 you could use the aggregate functions as [window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-functions-usage.html) -

```
SELECT AVG(lead_time)
FROM (
    SELECT
        DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) AS lead_time,
        (DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date) - AVG(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)) OVER()) / STDDEV(DATEDIFF(shipped_date, order_date)) OVER() AS zscore
    FROM orders
) t
WHERE zscore BETWEEN -0.96 AND 1.96;
```

Without example data, this is untested but I think it is correct.

Comment: The last one really works.